# How can I change the color scheme on PuTTY?. I'm not finding any Apply/Save option after I make changes?

Tags: ssh, putty, colors

If I do click on the System menu at the upper left corner of the PuTTY window.

- Select Change Settings > Window > Colours

After this, I'm not finding any "SAVE" option there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the colour scheme on PuTTY?](https://superuser.com/questions/198452/how-do-i-change-the-colour-scheme-on-putty)

Comment: You're not asking how to change the scheme; you're asking how to save changes. Please [edit] your question title to reflect this. I believe the answer is [in this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/198452/how-do-i-change-the-colour-scheme-on-putty#comment201494_198456).

Comment: @Ashton It's better if you go through the description before commenting something!

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski IDK why you pointing my question to that comment. Mine is different, I have explained what is my problem and what changes I'm expecting!

Comment: I did, I also read the last answer on that page which explains what you need to do to save changes.

Answer (score 2):

The Save option is located under the Session category. You can save the settings (including colour) per Session. Make sure you enter a name in the Saved Sessions field and click Save.