# Changing terminal settings from Putty client

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I' using Putty client to connect to ssh server running on Virtualbox Linux machine. I'm trying to change the prompt color by setting the PS1 variable like so:

```
export PS1="\u@\h:\e[0;1m\w\$\e[m"
```

but it's apparently not working - the prompt is still the same color. When i type the command directly on my Virtualbox Linux machine it does work. Moreover i've noticed that also changing the `TERM` variable doesn't has an effect when running in Putty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/198452/how-do-i-change-the-colour-scheme-on-putty .  Also, consider using mtputty to save multiple sessions' settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `terminal-type` string prior to connecting.

Setting the "xterm-color" type lets bash (and others) know that your tty supports color.

You can also do some fun things with the environment variables... but that is another discussion for another day.

[image: putty config window]

Comment: Setting the terminal-type doesn't help either. I can't set the color like on native Linux console.

Answer (score 0):

... it looks like your color choices don't exist.

```
Black        0;30     Dark Gray     1;30
Red          0;31     Light Red     1;31
Green        0;32     Light Green   1;32
Brown/Orange 0;33     Yellow        1;33
Blue         0;34     Light Blue    1;34
Purple       0;35     Light Purple  1;35
Cyan         0;36     Light Cyan    1;36
Light Gray   0;37     White         1;37
```

Perhaps you meant something more like this for red:

```
export PS1="\u@\h:\e[0;31m\w\$\e[00m"
```

Comment: Yes, when i use one of this it works but It's still strange since 2;2 DOES works when on native, non ssh (VirtualBox) console. It produces just light blue color.

Comment: Can You answer my last question?

Comment: I honestly have no clue what `2;2` is talking about.  Could you provide a complete prompt-string including what you're talking about?